# Multiple restarts the container on OpenShift

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, .net-core, openshift-3

I have an API deployed on OpenShift with 15 Pods to serve requests.
Each pod has 300MB and 512MB of CPU and memory respectively.
It turns out that among these 15 pods, some work harder than others and therefore end up restarting a lot more.

I would like to balance the load between the pods to distribute this processing and thus try to reduce restarts.

Does anyone know how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Bare metal Openshift? Or a cloud version like Azure Red Hat OpenShift?

Comment: use oc describe pod

Comment: Openshift OnPremises

Comment: do you have sticky sessions activated? or are you using round-robin as balancing strategy? you actually didn't supply any actual proof that the requests are not balanced, one could simply argue that the pod `p5psm` is in a bad host and that's why it has more restarts... do you have any telemetry (like application insights or datadog) that support your claim? otherwise we might go on a goose-chase here...